# Markdown custom ID gets injected to heading tags

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, html-heading

I'm trying to make a website with Jekyll, but everytime I use `#something` to get a first level heading tag of `<h1>something</h1>`, instead I get `<h1 id=something>something</h1>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, let me give myself some sort of answer.
apparently if I add this to my markdown file:

```
{::options auto_ids="false" /}
```

then auto id generation turns off. I'm using Kramdown as a parser.

Comment: @Tom's answer is clearly better than this one (it will work with all files, not just one)

Comment: This helped me a lot, since I was looking for a way to only enable auto_ids for specific pages and jekyll won't let me do this.

Answer (score 3):

A better bet would be to put the option into your _config.yml file, then you don't need to include it in every markdown file.
For kramdown you'd need to include:

```
kramdown:
  auto_ids: false
```

Source: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/